# why does codeigniter give me this error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing, path, resize

I'm trying to make thumbmails of user imaes. However, I always get 'path to the image is incorrect."

my code:

```
$settings = array(
            'source_image' => '/videotuts/profilepic/userimg.png',
            'create_thumb' => TRUE,
            'new_image' => '/videotuts/profilepic'
        );
$this->load->library('image_lib',$settings);

$r = $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Does it matter that codeigniter is not installed in my website root?

Comment: I'm not familiar with codeigniter, but my guess is that `source_image` and `new_image` are specified as absolute paths (absolute on file system, not relative to website root) and this causes a problem. Try to replace `source_image` path with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/videotuts/profilepic/userimg.png'`, do the same with `new_image` path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at all the answers and comments, let me assume that you have codeigniter in folder `/htdocs/videotuts/`, notice there is a `/` in the starting. So you `index.php` is located in `htdocs/videotuts/index.php`. Codeigniter libraries will follow any path respective to `index.php` and hence there should be a path `/videotuts/profilepic/userimg.png` under `/htdocs/videotuts/`or the full path should be '/htdocs/videotuts/videotuts/profilepic/userimg.png'. If its not the same, remove the unwanted folder name from your paths. You don't need to use `APPPATH` or `FCPATH` or `BASEPATH`. 2ndly, if you are creating thumbnails, I hope you have correctly set read write perms for image folders.

Comment: I havn't tested your suggestions yet, but I'll test them ASAP, but looking at your argumentation and your detailed explanation, your answer seems to be good, so giving it +1 anyways.

Comment: thanks for upvoting, I have been using CI for last 2.5 years for most of my personal projects and recently finished a small project using CI2

Comment: I have found the error. I could solve it by adding a dot before the path, so that it became `./profilepic/userimg.png'. I don't know why though, because I always thought that  the dot just referred to the current directory, therefore, it was only useful when you used 2 of them to go up one level.

Comment: Frederik, thats what I said. CI will follow all paths relative to `index.php`. So setting your path to `./profilepic/userimg.png` means you have set path to current working directory which holds `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Is that folder actually at that absolute path on your server? If not, experiment with using the APPPATH constant.

```
'source_image' => APPPATH.'videotuts/profilepic/userimg.png',
```

Comment: Is `APPPATH` something that is defined in CodeIgniter? Does it have `/` at the end of the path, i.e., is it `/www/htdocs` or `/www/htdocs/`?

Comment: My codeigniter installation is placed at htdocs/videotuts/. But, because I thought that relative paths were seen relative to the index.php file, I first tried using them without the videotuts directory added to the paths. Then, I tried it with the videotuts part added, to see if it was calculated relative to the site root.

Comment: @binarLV it does have a trailing slash, defined in the codeigniter front controller.

Comment: @Frederik Creemers it's not relative to site root. Either supply an absolute path or a path relative to the front controller (index.php)

Comment: that's the strange thing, the path I specified before ading /videotuts was relative to the front controller, but that didn't work either. Does it also give this error if the file type is not supported or the file is corrupted?

Comment: @Frederik Creemers, when specifying relative path, you didn't use `/` character in the front of that path, did you? I.e., you used `profilepic/userimg.png` (relative path) and not `/profilepic/userimg.png` (absolute path, because starts with `/`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CI 2.0.2, your APPPATH is application folder. You should use FCPATH, try this:

```
'source_image' => FCPATH.'videotuts/profilepic/userimg.png',
```